# Return need exactly same generics sequence

Tags: java, generics, types, enums

I am trying to execute this:

```
public class Value<T extends Number> {}
public class Currency<V extends Value> {}
public class ValuePair<V extends Value, C extends Currency<V>> {}
public class UnitStack<E extends Enum, V extends Value> {}
public class UnitCurrency<V extends Value, U extends Enum, S extends UnitStack<U, V>> extends Currency<V> {}
public class CustomStack extends UnitStack<CustomStack.CustomEnum, Value<Double>> {
  public enum CustomEnum {
    ;
  }
}

public class Program {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    test();
  }
  public static ValuePair<Value<Double>, UnitCurrency<Value<Double>, Enum, UnitStack<Enum, Value<Double>>>> test() {
    return new ValuePair<Value<Double>, UnitCurrency<Value<Double>, CustomStack.CustomEnum, CustomStack>>();
  }
}
```

I am using this abstract structure for get a type safe unit system. So it is important for me that this structure is that complicated. The error that appears here while executing this stuff is somehow not logical:

```
/tmp/java_UHRI1F/Program.java:6: error: incompatible types: ValuePair<Value<Double>,UnitCurrency<Value<Double>,CustomEnum,CustomStack>> cannot be converted to ValuePair<Value<Double>,UnitCurrency<Value<Double>,Enum,UnitStack<Enum,Value<Double>>>>
    return new ValuePair<Value<Double>, UnitCurrency<Value<Double>, CustomStack.CustomEnum, CustomStack>>();
           ^
1 error
```

Because the CustomEnum extends Enum and CustomStack extends UnitStack. But if you using Generics in a return sequence you need exactly the same class which is here a problem. Is their any solution to this problem with generics ?

**Here some explainations to [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner) and all others that do not understand why I am using generics so often:**

I understand `Currency` only as self representing that can display a compatible Values. I am actually got huge abstract system that working fine with this behaviour. The `Program.class` is actually a `class` that transform a value from one `UnitStack` to another `UnitStack`.

I actually want to create a abstract interface for `Enums` but it seems to be the case that `Enums` can not be extend with my interfaces that is the reason why I am using inbody `Enums`. Also I got other problems in the past with `Enums` because they seem to be static final and not cloneable, which makes Enums for me often useless.

`Value` is used so often, because I got `RangeValue`, I need to have one Number Value that is can be used for different math tasks and I am using it for logic cases that can be solved with different number types for example if you buying raw eggs you can not buy a 0.75 Egg or a more technical real world example would be the integration of different apis for crypto currency which are using different number types.

The changes you are suggest are not solving the error and forcing me to use even more generics. Sorry but that is the case. As I known as [ernest-k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5761558/ernest-k) comment generics are invariant, which creates this error even if I add the Number generic to every class.

**More explaination to a solution that I am searching for**

I just want to know if their is any solution to this problem without using generics again. A solution that force me to use generics that need to be defined by the types init would force me to create a instance for every unit transformation, which was the first idea but would cost a lot of resources.

Here my interface for the `UnitStackTranslation`:

```
public interface UnitStackTranslation<F extends UnitStack, T extends UnitStack, FV extends ValuePair, TV extends ValuePair> {
TV translateFrom(FV value, F from, T to);
FV translateTo(TV value, T to, F from);
}
```

Comment: Generic type parameters are invariant. Inheritance only applies to the base type (`ValuePair`, in this case); so you cannot use subtypes anywhere between outer `<` and `>`, unless wildcards or bounded parameters are used.

Comment: You have raw types in there: `Currency` needs to be `Currency<T extends Number, V extends Value<T>>`, or similar: and anywhere you currently have `extends Value`. Honestly, I think you are overusing generics here.